# "cannot connect to the server at this time. you can continue working with this list, but some data may not be available"

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007

I have a List which is having around 7000 items in it.while opening that list in datasheet view it is giving error .

Below is the error after selecting datasheet view :

****"Cannot connect to the server at this time.  You can continue working with this list, but some data may not be available."

Unable to retrieve all data.(At the bottom of data sheet view)****

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should know that SharePoint 2007 is no longer supported by Microsoft, which means that certain bug fixes for issues that are discovered (maybe on this issue as well) are not provided.

See a similar post here: [SharePoint Error “The list cannot be displayed in Datasheet View”.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067520/sharepoint-error-the-list-cannot-be-displayed-in-datasheet-view)

Besides that, here are a few things you can check to narrow down this issue:

1. If you are displaying all 7000 items in the datasheet view, consider performance issue caused by **List View Threshold** limit. [Raise the limit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59#__bkmkchangelimit) in Central Administration and see if the error goes away.
2. If you have workflows attached to this list and list workflow column in the current list view, hide them from the list view and then test again.

   Reference: [Sharepoint list dataheet view error "Cannot connect to the server at this time. You can continue working with this list, but some data may not be available".](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/1cfa3181-8a1e-4692-9890-d537c8b097d4/sharepoint-list-dataheet-view-error-quotcannot-connect-to-the-server-at-this-time-you-can?forum=sharepointadmin)

A few more suggestions here: [Cannot connect to server at this time. Your list cannot be published](http://nazishalirizvi.blogspot.com/2013/09/cannot-connect-to-server-at-this-time.html)